# featherlight.js reset css option removes previous/next buttons

Tags: featherlight.js

using featherlight.js with the gallery extension. When you specify the resetCss option as "true" it seems to stop the previous/next elements from being generated at all - is this supposed to happen??

```
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-reset-css="true" data-featherlight-filter="a">
  <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_b.jpg"><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_q.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_3403152632_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_f652202d1b_q.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_q.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/twalkers86/umyj7wwv/

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a bug, sorry about this.